# How to add Hyperlink to Image PDFKIT Nodejs

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, pdfkit

I'm new to pdfkit, need to add hyperlink to image. added **link** to options but still not working.

> doc.image('utils/pdfItinerary/images/test.png', {link:'www.google.com', width: 300, height:80})

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this. Convert your image to base64 string and then use the string as the image buffer:

```
    // Add an image to the PDF. The image data is base64, so it needs to be converted to a Buffer first.
    const base64Image = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAhJJREFUaEPtmMsrrlEUxn8uwyMjI5eOkvhPSLmMmZykTie5TJjIn0BIUjJxzvAM3P8UpFDEHEPEU+8rFN+71t4fvtp7+q3b8zzrXXvtr4oKP1UVXj8JwFcrmBRICgQykFookMBg96RAMIWBAZICbwhsAfqAHuAn0JT9fgGcATvAJnAeSPyzeywFGoHZp8KGgZoSxT0A/4GpDFQQlhgA+oEN4IexkhtgCNgy+r0yDwUwDswB1c4ipMYksOj0D9pGxbxawVt8XrNADHiV8Cqgj/PA0TbvEa126gAurUp4AawDv6zJStivASPWmB4AGpUnBaaNtZb7bPRq5BY+HgBjwELhDDbDUWDZ4uIBsA90WZIYbPeyS7CwiwfAMdBWOIPN8Cj7mAt7eQBoYlgvraIF3QJ1RY1l990AXAP15QYgmdstSQy2h0Cnwd6lQMV/xBp1SxaWDLZ/gBWDvUuBZuC0DBfZHdAKlP0iE0G69rX7xzyrwG9rQM8UUg49YLTMmUbeB8Vp+miZu/osAMrTDWxHaCWt01rNFct8vArkibQXzQe8CVT8RMhQCAUgIL1Pq8VfRzupbQazh76Z+dwhBgDFagBmAI3B2hLViPV/wLSn59/GjgUgj6uXWv63ikbiy79V9IbYzZ6OplH5ESGxAbhbweuYAHiZi+WXFIjFpDdOUsDLXCy/pEAsJr1xkgJe5mL5VbwCj2zFRDFwWwuaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'; // your base64 image data here
    const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Image, 'base64');

    doc.image(imageBuffer, 0, 0, { fit: [200, 200], link: 'https://www.google.com' });
```

Hope it helps.